# Facebook Like Button in iframe without posting

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm trying to implement a Facebook like button within an iframe of a constrained width and height.  The button works, but after submitting the like and incrementing the count, it then displays a large textarea field to post something about the page to your Facebook feed.  Unfortunately the iframe is too small to display this and thus . I looked through the attribute values and it looks like there is no way to do this, but is there any way of preventing this or am I at the mercy of Facebook's plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually had the same problem but at this point, there is no other way than clipping it

Comment: Thanks, actually now that I think about it, it doesn't get clipped, but rather it displays beneath the button.  The problem is that the button is aligned to the bottom of the iframe and so when the post form comes up, it pushes a bunch of the other elements up in order for it to display itself without being clipped.  Because the iframe is set not to be scrolled, that top part of it then is inaccessible - unless the user reloads the page.  How annoying!

Comment: I ended up making scrolling auto.  It's not idea by any stretch, but at least users can scroll back the content that's hidden when they click on that button...